# I expect it to be 57 sometime!

Tags: computer-puzzle

Which famous quote is this simple Java code representing?

```
public class Foo {

    private int result = 38;

    public void foo() {
        do {
            thing(result);
        } while (result == 38);
    }

    public void thing(int i) {
        i += 19;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo().foo();
    }

}
```

---

<sub>P.S.: Sorry, I know it's easy</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

> Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results. Albert Einstein

Comment: I agree with your answer. But I can't remember if java is pass by reference or pass by copy by default...

Comment: @Goinghamateur It's pass by value. Primitive types, like in this example, just get copied. If you're interested: I just found more detailed explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: Thankee, I found a very good comment about balloons to clarify everything for me.